# How to include Mongo to Spring?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I want include Mongo to Spring. So I have spring.context.xml

```
<mongo:mongo host="localhost" port="27017" />
<mongo:db-factory dbname="employee_service" />

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
</bean>
```

pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

And class:

```
@Document(collection = "vacancy")
public class Vacancy {
@Id
private String id;
private String description;
//setters and getters
}
```

so when I try to deploy my application on tomcat, I have exceptions:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [spring.config.xml]:     
Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class 
[org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested 
exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/objenesis/ObjenesisStd
```

NOTE: I hava Spring 4.x version

Comment: You obviously lack a class at Runtime, because you have a `NoClassDefFoundError`.